# Altering the message space of Paillier

Tags: public-key

Is there any obstacle if we restrict in Paillier the plaintext values to be drawn from $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_N$ as the original scheme indicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you can always restrict your message space to a subset of the message space for which the scheme is defined (which is the case here).

Note that in practice you will deal with messages relatively prime to $N$, i.e., from $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$, anyways (any message not coprime to $N$ - except zero - would allow you to factor $N$ - thus its very unlikely to hit such a message).

Comment: Note that one can compute an encryption of zero from two encryptions of the same messages because of the additive homomorphism though

Comment: @FlorianBourse Yes, due to the homomorphism you may get a ciphertext to a message outside your space (i.e., 0). But I am not sure what your point exactly is.

Comment: The point is just that you cannot force all ciphertext to be for non-zero elements. A friend of mine wanted to use additively homomorph encryption with non-zero elements at some point to build a protocol, and restricting the message space isn't enough.
As the question is not really precise, I wanted to add this comment on your correct answer for more details ;)

Comment: @FlorianBourse Yes, I totally agree. But the question asks for restricting (by that I mean input to the Enc algorithm) and not enforcing :) Clearly, if you have a scheme that is homomorphic you can always produce ciphertexts to messages outside a restricted message space by means of the homomorphism.

Comment: @FlorianBourse this can be done by any homomorphic scheme since they are not supposed to be CCA secure. Meaning, the adversary can alter on its will the ciphertext